# How to run Selenium in pre-existing browser?

Tags: python, html, selenium, cookies

So, I  made a web page on which I have a button that when clicked runs Selenium code (I'm writing in Python). I want my Selenium code to run in this existing, manually opened browser(in which I pre-opened this web page) rather than open new browser window. I already looked through all the similar questions here, but every answer requires opening chrome in debugging mode (which I want to avoid) or doesn't use this manually opened browser but some else. My idea is that there needs to be a way for me to get session id of my existing browser and "give" it to Selenium so it knows where to run. Any ideas, solutions? :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For now, you cannot do that and as far I know, you can achieve that in debugging mode only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***It's officially not supported.***

*However, there is some working code which claims to support this:, Also this is in java I am sure you can make in your desire language*

https://web.archive.org/web/20171214043703/http://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium-java/

Comment: Yes, but if I got it right, this code recycles session that was made in Selenium code and not one pre-opened manually before even Selenium ran.